# @OneToOne Mapped as @OneToMany

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

//@OneToOne Relationship turned mapped as @OneToMany by Spring data JPA / //hibernate in MySQL

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product extends DataJournal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Double price;

    private Date dom;
    private Date expiryDate;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "product", optional = false)
    private Stock stock;
    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
public class Stock extends DataJournal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Long quantity;
    private Long reOrderLabel;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="product_id")
    private Product product;
    //getters and setters
}
```

//    Relation between Product and stock is as @OneToOne but it is mapped //as @OneToMany in Mysql, the following are reversed mysql database and //relation 
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYD3O.jpg
    [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f3f9.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you are letting Hibernate to generate the DDL for you, try using [`@JoinColumn(unique = true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#unique()) in your `Stock` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
public class Stock extends DataJournal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Long quantity;
    private Long reOrderLabel;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="product_id", unique = true)
    private Product product;
    //getters and setters
}
```